Relationship Navigation Entity Framework Memory Leakage
I have a query in EF 5.0.0, where I am using a query
result.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new SchoolEvent_model){
    EventId = x.Id,
    EventName = x.Name,
    EventDate = x.Start_Date.Value
}

This is working fine but when I am adding following line to that it is causing memory leak.
FRCalendarSession = x.FRCalendar.FRCalendarSession

I know AsEnumerable convert into the memory but the thing it is working fine without adding.
One more thing to ask, we took 3 days to find that this is the pain point leaking memory. How ca we find the issue faster. I was using Azure kql queries, dotMemory tools but its hard to identify which method is causing memory leaks
I tried to see the converted SQL and run it on server. It is running in 0 sec with and without that statement.
I am expecting to use this FRCalendarSession without memory leak.

anyone her wants to answer my question
